# Android x86 Network interfaces Down

Tags: android

I am working on an ANDROID application , and I am using Oracle VM and Android x86 for testing, I wanted to download a newer version some 3.x + , and I found no generic ones except for 2.2.
However, I used a 4.0 version which was for ASUS (Note: Mine is HP), when I tried to connect to eclipse by getting its ip, I found the network interfaces all down. How can I bring them up , or is there any other method to connect them to eclipse?

Comment: This question is confusing to me. Oracle VM and Android x86 could mean several things. Are you talking about running the emulator with virtualization? Did you try running the emulator outside of Eclipse?

Comment: yes I tried the emulator , but it is too slow ..... yes I am using oracle virtual machine and running Android on it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to set the network settings on Android x86:

On the console (Alt - Cursor Left)

Set IP address:
    ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0

Set Gateway:
    route add default gw 192.168.1.254 dev eth0

Set DNS if needed.

Comment: Might help knowing that setting DNS is another inobvious command; something like `setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8`.